# I stuck with get out from while loop in method

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am writing program that asks user to type seven names of product.

what I try to do is if there is duplicate, then repeat the method.

I used while loop but I stuck.

If I put a,b,c,d,e,f,g at the first time, method ends and moves on to next method.

But if I typed a,a,b,c,d,e,f, program repeats same method and even if I type a,b,c,d,e,f,g, it  gets in infinite loop.

here is my codes.

in main....

```
    purchasedList.setShopList();
```

in purchasedList class...

```
    public void setShopList() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // print out description.
    System.out.println("\n- Only have one entry of any type in the item list.");
    System.out.println("- The name of items cannot be longer than 16 characters.");

    System.out.println("\nType seven products.");
    boolean sameNames = true;
    while (sameNames == true) {
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            String n = keyboard.nextLine();
            name.add(n);
            name.set(i,name.get(i).toUpperCase());
        }
        sameNames = checkName();
    }
}
// accessor.
public ArrayList<String> getShopList () {
    return name;
}
// check duplicate.
public boolean checkName() {

    Set<String> uniqueName = new HashSet<String>();

    boolean foundName = false;

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (!uniqueName.add(name.get(i))) { // check duplicate
            foundName = true;
        }
    }
    if (foundName == true) {
        System.out.println("※ There is a duplicate.  Try it again.");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

my checkName() method is fine because in my last project it worked.

in my last project, I put while loop in main like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    PurchasedList purchasedList = new PurchasedList();

    .
    .
    .

    boolean sameNames = true;
    boolean tooLong = true;
    while (sameNames == true || tooLong == true) {
        System.out.println("\nType seven products.");
        purchasedList.setShopList();
        sameNames = purchasedList.checkName();
        tooLong = purchasedList.checkLength();
    }
```

but this time, because my professor wants me to make all operations are done within a method, so I try to fix.

I tried to solve it by myself in last 8 hours, but I could not get the solution.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: are you 100% sure your loop is `while (sameNames == true) {` and  not `while (sameNames = true) {`? Either way, you should simply write `while (sameNames) {`...

Comment: Even if I use 'while (sameNames) {', it still same.

Comment: You forget to clear names on your purchasedList. If you only add elements, once you add duplicates you will stay there forever

Comment: If you do not mind, may I ask you how to do this clear()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line.

```
 if (foundName == true) {
    System.out.println("※ There is a duplicate.  Try it again.");
  ->  name = new ArrayList<String>();
    return true;
```

right now you are adding new names to the end of the array, and then setting them to upper case in the start of the array.

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        String n = keyboard.nextLine(); //Say I type in g on my second try
        name.add(n); //This add g to the end of the array
        name.set(i,name.get(i).toUpperCase()); //And this sets name[0] to G.
    }
```

this means your name array is getting longer, instead of resetting.

Comment: I didn't post my code correctly, I put "sameNames = checkName();" in while loop.

Comment: Do you ever reset name if you find a duplicate? You should clear names, or you are just adding more items to the end.

Comment: O, do I have to clear() because it is arrayList? In that case, how should I do that?

Comment: I just tried to add if (sameNames == true) { name.clear();} right below while loop, but it didn't work.

Comment: name = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: I already have 'private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();' in my class

Comment: add it where i said above and see if that works. adding it after the while loop won't help because it will never reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever clean **name**? It appears you just keep adding to it, so the previous entrances are still there in loop's next round. And therefore there will always be a duplicate if you use same input as before (the order will not matter).

This change should do it:

```
while (sameNames == true) {
        name = newArrayList <String>();
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            String n = keyboard.nextLine();
            name.add(n);
            name.set(i,name.get(i).toUpperCase());
        }
        sameNames = checkName();
    }
```

So new **name** ArrayList is created every time. (Garbage collector will take care of the old ones, if necessary.) If **name** is already created somewhere else, then think if you really need it there - as far as I see you use it to gather input, and this happens in the method setShopList() so it appears you do not need it earlier than this.

Comment: my bad, I didnt post my code correctly.  I put sameNames = checkName();" in while loop